# Why adding 4 "zero" bits (0000) to the end of the segment register address to get segment address in physical memory?

Tags: memory, x86, register

Why, do we have to find an address in memory in which there is 20 bits free space which have 16 bits for segment register and 4 "Zero" bits?

Like, if the CS register is 346AH, the code segment in main memory will be 346A0H, which is 20 bits. why do we do that?

Memory segments are 64Kbytes (?), what happens to the rest of the space, appart from that 20 bits?

Sorry i'm not much good at computer architecture!

Comment: so how long is a segment , say, code segment in main memory?

Comment: "For backward compatibility, all x86 CPUs start in "real mode" with no memory protection, fixed 64 KiB segments, and only 20-bit (1024 KiB) addressing. An 80286 or later processor must be switched into another mode by software in order to use its full address space and advanced MMU features."

Comment: Depends on the register used.  "Four of the segment registers: CS, SS, DS, and ES are forced to 0, and the limit to 264. The segment registers FS and GS can still have a nonzero base address."  [Memory segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation)

Comment: it is written in my book that they are maximum 64KB and my book is in persian so it is not usefull for u to tell u the name!

Comment: I don't need to know the name of your book to know the information is dated.

Comment: Apparently you're referring to **x86** segmentation, as originally used in the Intel 8086/88 CPUs.  This kind of *"segment"* is not universal.  The x86 segment is a *truncated* address of only 16 address bits.  Hence the need to append the four truncated zero bits to obtain the actual start of the x86 segment in 20-bit memory space.

Comment: @Ramhound what do u mean by 20 bit "addressing" ?

Comment: @parvin - Your question specifically refers to 20-bit addressing. I quoted a Wikipedia article for convenence to highlight the fact your talking about a "real mode" not ["protected mode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode#Segment_addressing) which has [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#I.2FO_MMU_virtualization_.28AMD-Vi_and_Intel_VT-d.29) features

Comment: @sawdust aha, and what do u mean by "actual start" of segment ?

Comment: @parvin - He means an offset.  16-bits would be 0x346A

Comment: *"what do u mean by "actual start" of segment"* -- The first byte of the x86 segment.  An x86 segment can be up to 64K bytes long.  You have to combine a (truncated 16-bit) segment address with an (16-bit) offset to generate a 20-bit address.   But the x86 segment address as to be multiplied by 16 (aka append four zero bits) before you can add the offset. An offset of zero is the start of the x86 segment.

Comment: @sawdust why is the start of a segment, 20 bits?

Comment: What does this have to do with `segmentation-fault` tag?

Answer (score 2):

> Like, if the CS register is 346AH, the code segment in main memory will be 346A0H, which is 20 bits. why do we do that?

Apparently you're referring to [x86 segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Memory_segmentation), as originally used in the Intel 8086/88 CPUs.  This kind of "segment" is not universal. There are other definitions for memory "[segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation)".

In a historical context, you need to realize that silicon and (ferrite) memory used to be very expensive.  To counter the expensive mainframe computers, the [minicomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicomputer) emerged in the 1970s to provide a low-cost computer.  This focus on low cost usually meant a 16-bit address bus (e.g. DEC PDP, Data General Nova, HP 21xx), and up to 64KB of memory.  But as system requirements grew, more memory was often needed.

Memory schemes were devised that could still use the existing 16-bit addresses yet can access more memory.
The most common technique to expand the 64KB memory capacity with 16-bit addresses was to use memory banks, i.e. the actual upper-bits of the effective memory address are specified by a bank register.  The primary advantage of using memory banks is that it can be implemented in the memory subsystem (i.e. external to the CPU), and therefore retrofitted to any CPU.
With the advent of microprocessors, systems using 16-bit addressing (e.g. Intel 8051, Zilog Z80) tended to evolve in a similar fashion, i.e. incorporating banked memory.

The segment addressing as used by Intel x86 (and at least one other system that I know of) is integrated with the processor and hence more versatile.
Whereas a memory bank can only occupy a fixed region in the original memory space, x86 segments provide access to an expanded 20-bit address space using a 16-bit offset combined with a specification of a segment register.

The x86 segment address is actually a 20-bit address truncated to only 16 address bits.
That segment can start on any paragraph (the address modulo 16 is zero).
Hence the need to append the four truncated zero bits to obtain the actual start of the x86 segment in 20-bit memory space.
Depending on the [x86 memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Memory_models), the x86 software could use primarily 16-bit "addresses" (just like older software), but could access more effective memory than the older 16-bit address software could.

IOW x86 segments was a method of expanding the hardware to a 20-bit address bus, but allow the software to use mostly 16-bit "addresses", and not require 20-bit arithmetic (i.e. 20-bit wide registers and data).